# Delete table row using "isempty"

Tags: vba, ms-word

Can someone please tell me why, when I run this code, it skips the **tbl.Range.Rows(i).Delete** line when there are rows in my table which are empty?

Many thanks

Debbie

Dim i As Long
Dim tbl As Table

```
Set tbl = ActiveDocument.Tables(2)

For i = tbl.Range.Rows.Count To 1 Step -1
  With tbl
    If IsEmpty(tbl.Range.Rows(i)) = True Then
      tbl.Range.Rows(i).Delete
    End If
  End With
Next
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple answer is that, in Word, a row is never empty - it always contains end-of-cell and end-of-row characters. Try:

```
Dim r As Long
With ActiveDocument.Tables(2)
  For r = .Rows.Count To 1 Step -1
    With .Rows(r)
      If Len(.Range.Text) = .Cells.Count * 2 + 2 Then .Delete
    End With
  Next r
End With
```

Note that the above code won't work if the table has vertically-merged/split cells.

Comment: Thank you, that works perfectly.  I appreciate your explanation of why it didn't work using IsEmpty.